# IDEA подчеркивает asssertEquals

Tags: intellij-idea, junit

Я недавно начал знакомиться с UNIT-тестированием.

В проекте в external libraries junit4 значится:

[image]

Для класса Account создал тест CTRL+SHIFT+T  - Testing Library выбрал JUNIT4.

Ругается IDEA - Подчеркивает asssertEquals.

Импортировал же в шапке Assert.

Comment: Assert пишется с 2 s, а у вас с 3.

Comment: Ух ты, емае...так же лохануться...это все происходит когда как зомби возле компа ))) Спасибо, вот же я....

Answer (score 0):

Папка src в проекте покрашена синим. В IntelliJ это папка исходников. Папка с модульными тестами должна быть покрашена зеленым. В родной [шпаргалке](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/tutorial-test-driven-development.html) IntelliJ на эту тему есть отдельный пункт.